# Android p2p0 interface has ipv6 address

Tags: android, networking, p2p, ipv6, ipv4

I downloaded OS Monitor app to inspect all network interfaces. I discover:

on p2p0 interface, there is a default ipv6 address before any ad hoc (wifi direct) connection. The value is similar to wlan0#ipv6 address with one bit flipped. The ipv4 address, however, is empty. The same behavior was confirmed by printing out NetworkInterface object in Android SDK.

It confuses me. I think for wifi direct, before joining any group, there shouldn't be any ip address assigned, neither ipv6 nor ipv4. Did I miss anything here?

Any comment/suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: what is the ipv6 address that you can see?

Comment: I see: p2p0: ipv6: fe80:860:6eff:fe2d:33cf/64. It looks like a totally valid ipv6 address. Also it's the same address for wlan0 ipv6.

Comment: @Lily: Please do copy & paste. I suppose there is a `::` after `fe80`, not a mere `:`.

Comment: I couldn't copy it. I was using an app to show ifconfig info... but thanks for catching the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a link local address.  The block fe80::/64 is reserved for link local addresses.

Explained by Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address).

When you have a connection, you should get a public IPv6 address.